# I can't verify my contract on etherscan

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, erc-20

I can't verify my contract on etherscan-rinkeby.

It shows something wrong about ABI-encoded format.

The contract address is following.

What is the right ABI and how to generate it？

Any help is much appreciated.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    if (a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a / b;
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}
contract owned {
    address public owner;
    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        require(newOwner != address(0));
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}
interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) 

external; }

contract BasicToken {
    function totalSupply () public view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining);
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) public returns (bool success);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 _value);
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 _value);
}
contract EdenToken is BasicToken, owned {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    string public name = "Eden Token";
    string public symbol= "EDT";
    uint8 public decimals = 8;
    uint256 public totalSupply = 200000000;  
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;  
    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

    constructor() public {
        totalSupply = totalSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);
        owner = msg.sender;        
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                                            
    }
    function totalSupply () public view returns (uint256){
        return totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256){
        return balanceOf[_owner];
    }


    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining){
        return allowance[_owner][_spender];
    }
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) internal {
        require(_to != 0x0);
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);

   }


    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        require(!frozenAccount[msg.sender]);
        require(_to != address(owner));
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
   }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        require(!frozenAccount[msg.sender]);
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
        require(_to != address(owner));  
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);    
        return true;
    }

     function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public 
        returns (bool success) {
        require(_spender != address(owner));
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }
     function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) public returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }
    }
    function burn(uint256 _value) onlyOwner public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            
        totalSupply -= _value;                      
        emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }


     function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) onlyOwner public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             
        totalSupply -= _value;                              
        emit Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) public onlyOwner {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        emit Transfer(0, owner, mintedAmount);
        emit Transfer(owner, target, mintedAmount);
    }

    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) public onlyOwner {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        emit FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    } 
    function unFreezeAccount(address target) public onlyOwner{
        frozenAccount[target] = false;
        emit FrozenFunds(target, false);
    } 
    function setName(string _name) onlyOwner public {
        name = _name;
    }
    function setsymbol(string _symbol) onlyOwner public {
        symbol = _symbol;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you add the contract address?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to verify your contract both on Rinkeby and Ropsten.
It is here:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xe9ee5a70ff68e12d5f10fca6792a3667ac281c82#code

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x44d901bec6e6032b816e6df7c494f4c7242065c1#code

Make sure that when you verify all those parameters match:

- Compiler version
- Optimization ( if you don't know if your compilation was optimized then try Yes and No. That just two tries so it is not a big deal )
- Contract name. It must match contract you deployed. If you deployed EdenToken then you should type EdenToken.

There is nothing wrong with your code and it can be verified.

You can also send us your contract address so we can try to do verification for you.

I am not 100 % sure, but error message you get means that source code provided by you for verification doesn't match deployed contract. Etherscan generate ABI and check if it is matching already deployed contract.